# Overwriting the class on a `Html.EditorFor`

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, textinput, class-attributes

by the default with

```
<%: Html.EditorFor(m => m.ConfirmationHeadline) %>
```

the output is:

```
 <input type="text" value="" 
        name="ConfirmationHeadline" id="ConfirmationHeadline" 
        class="text-box single-line">
```

As you can see, the input appends already a `class` attribute. Well, this should not be a problem, just use

```
<%: Html.EditorFor(m => m.ConfirmationHeadline, new { @class="span-11 last"}) %>
```

and should work... **err... nope!**

this will output the exact same code!

though, works fine with `Html.TextAreaFor()`

How can I remove the class `text-box single-line` from ever appear so my own classes could be appended? any T4 template I should edited?

Thank you for all the help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no way to customize the value of the emitted class attribute when using built-in editor templates via the `EditorFor` method. It hard-codes the class value (more info available here: http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-3-default-templates.html)

You have two options:

1. Write your own custom template that supports the extra functionality. Have a look here for more details: http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-4-custom-object-templates.html
2. Process the output of the `EditorFor` method:

```
 <%: new HtmlString(Html.EditorFor(m=>m.ConfirmationHeadline).ToString()
        .Replace("class=\"text-box single-line\"", 
                 "class=\"text-box single-line span-11 last\"")) %>
```

Comment: after reading all parts of Brad's examples, I ended up using `<%: Html.TextBox("ConfirmationHeadline", null, new { @class = "span-11 last" })%>` Thank you for the links.

Answer (score 6):

In MCV 5.1 you can take advantage of htmlAttributes. Works like a charm...

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Enter your Name" } })
```

Answer (score 2):

asp.net mvc creates a file called site.css in the content folder. There you can see that the text-box class is set to a width of 30em by default. Reset it to something saner like 15em. The single-line class doesn't appear to be defined anywhere.

Comment: I always ditch the site.css!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TextBoxFor` instead

Comment: just to make sure, do you know the different between `EditorFor` and `TextboxFor`? You can [check it here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826173) for a quick answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and didn't like any of the solutions above. I also found a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4789512/2014613), but I didn't like those solutions either.  After some tooling around, I found something I liked, which let me continue to use the Editor Templates (which is something you should try to take advantage of whenever you can).  I posted the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15013551/2014613)

Answer (score -3):

try this code

```
@Html.Raw(
    Html.EditorFor(m => m.DataInicial).ToString()
    .Replace(
        "\"text-box single-line\"",
        "\"form-control text-box single-line\""))
```

Comment: You'd better add some explanation.

Comment: REVIEW of low quality post: Follow @Ipratlong advice. This answer in the current form is likely to be deleted for moderation reasons.