# Differences between Html.TextboxFor and Html.EditorFor in MVC and Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Why by default were these changed when adding a new "edit" view? What are advantages when using `EditorFor()` vs. `TextboxFor()`?

I found this

> By default, the Create and Edit  scaffolds now use the Html.EditorFor  helper instead of the Html.TextBoxFor helper. This improves support for  metadata on the model in the form of
> data annotation attributes when the  Add View dialog box generates a view.

[Quoted from here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/mvc3#template-scaffolding-improvements)

Comment: does anyone have an example of how this is done? for example writing editorfor a DatePicker?

Answer (score 175, accepted):

The advantages of `EditorFor` is that your code is not tied to an `<input type="text"`. So if you decide to change something to the aspect of how your textboxes are rendered like wrapping them in a `div` you could simply write a custom editor template (`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/string.cshtml`) and all your textboxes in your application will automatically benefit from this change whereas if you have hardcoded `Html.TextBoxFor` you will have to modify it everywhere. You could also use Data Annotations to control the way this is rendered.

Comment: There is a bug, probably in an old version. EditorFor doesn't recognize 'double'. For 'long' it considers it as 'int' and step="0.01" does not work in attributes so I used TextBoxFor and added @type='number' @step="0.01" so it worked

Answer (score 142):

**TextBoxFor**: It will render like text input html element corresponding to specified expression. In simple word it will always render like an input textbox irrespective datatype of the property which is getting bind with the control.

**EditorFor**: This control is bit smart. It renders HTML markup based on the datatype of the property. E.g. suppose there is a boolean property in model. To render this property in the view as a checkbox either we can use CheckBoxFor or EditorFor. Both will be generate the same markup.

What is the advantage of using EditorFor?

As we know, depending on the datatype of the property it generates the html markup. So suppose tomorrow if we change the datatype of property in the model, no need to change anything in the view. EditorFor control will change the html markup automatically.

Comment: great, simple answer which can easily absorbed even by a novice.

Comment: above description will help this link

https://forums.asp.net/t/1948071.aspx?EditorFor+and+EditorForModel

Comment: Is there ever a case where you should absolutely use TextBoxFor?

Answer (score 57):

The `Html.TextboxFor` always creates a textbox (`<input type="text" ...`).

While the EditorFor looks at the type and meta information, and can render another control or a template you supply.

For example for DateTime properties you can create a template that uses the jQuery DatePicker.

Comment: Any Example on how to implement jquery datepicker using editfor ?

Comment: thanks for simplifying the difference by using the date-time case.

Comment: @Peru, [here](http://instinctcoder.com/asp-net-mvc-4-jquery-datepicker/) or [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/using-the-html5-and-jquery-ui-datepicker-popup-calendar-with-aspnet-mvc/using-the-html5-and-jquery-ui-datepicker-popup-calendar-with-aspnet-mvc-part-4) is how to `implement jquery datepicker` and using it with  `EditorFor` is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23142692/2218697)

Comment: What if one wants to use the jquery datepicker with TextBoxFor?

Answer (score 8):

This is one of the basic differences not mentioned in previous comments:
`Readonly` property will work with textbox for and it will not work with `EditorFor`.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DateSoldOn, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
```

Above code works, where as with following you can't make control to **readonly**.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateSoldOn, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
```

Comment: You can make EditorFor readonly using the following syntax:  
  
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateSoldOn, new { htmlAttributes = new { @readonly = "readonly" } })

Answer (score 4):

There is also a slight difference in the html output for a string data type.

```
Html.EditorFor:  
<input id="Contact_FirstName" class="text-box single-line" type="text" value="Greg" name="Contact.FirstName">

Html.TextBoxFor:
<input id="Contact_FirstName" type="text" value="Greg" name="Contact.FirstName">
```

Comment: it's absolutly wrong answer, becuase the key difference is that Texbox returns input and editorfor returns your template where input is default template for editorfor.