# DateTime property not set properly on View Model

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

When my form with the view below is being posted to my controller action `MyAction`, I get a 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM date on my StartDate property, the format of the date coming in should be dd/MM/yyyy. I set it to 14/04/2011 on the form but it comes in 1/1/0001. Is there some culture or setting I'm not configuring properly?

In my controller, culture is set to

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-AU");
```

Action posted to:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(MyViewModel myViewModel)
{            
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View("Index", myViewModel);
    ...
```

View Model:

```
public class MyViewModel 
{
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayName("Start Date")]
    [Required]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
}
```

On View:

```
<%=Html.EditorFor(m => m.StartDate, new { style = "width: 110px;", @class = "date" })%>
```

Comment: Why do u use `EditorFor`? What does it output? Textbox?

Comment: @Aliostad, for reasons laid out here [MVC3 Html.TextboxFor vs. Html.EditorFor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826173/mvc3-html-textboxfor-vs-html-editorfor). Yes, it outputs a textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, I wasn't setting `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` in `MyAction`, only in the `Index` action.  I moved the logic into a `BaseController` class that all the controllers extend.