# MVC3 why use html.editorfor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am looking at MVC3 razor examples and seeing html.editorfor being utilized and also asked about a lot on this forum. Why can't i use `html.textboxfor` and `passwordfor`? Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

EditorFor has the advantage that it will try to render an editor associated to the data type.

For example: If you design your own [Editor Templates](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nunos/archive/2010/02/08/quick-tips-about-asp-net-mvc-editor-templates.aspx) they will automatically be rendered based upon the property's type or [UIHint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.uihintattribute.uihint.aspx)

A useful editor template might be one that generates a date picker when the property's type is a `DateTime`.

There are some other scenarios as well where the 'smart' EditorFor will generate the 'best' editor for the property such an example is when it renders a `<textarea>`  when tagging the property with `MultilineText`

Using TextBoxFor and PasswordFor are perfectly fine for those cases where you don't require 'a special editor'.  It might even simplify your life when having to set HtmlAttributes.

Comment: I would like to thank for both the answers. These cleared the whole thing. I accepted this answer due to the 2 links that i have been pointed to, great info.

Answer (score 6):

Ref [Differences between Html.TextboxFor and Html.EditorFor in MVC and Razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826173/mvc3-html-textboxfor-vs-html-editorfor) for clear the doubt about this..

> The HtmlTextboxFor always creates a `textbox (<input type="text" ...).`
>
> While the EditorFor looks at the type and meta information, and can
>   render another control or a template you supply.
>
> For example for DateTime properties you can create a template that
>   uses the jQuery DatePicker.

if you decide to change something to the aspect of how your textboxes are rendered like wrapping them in a div you could simply write a custom editor template `(~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/string.cshtml)` and all your textboxes in your application will automatically benefit from this change whereas if you have hardcoded `Html.TextBoxFor` you will have to modify it everywhere.