# Enable/Disable Html.EditorFor using ViewData

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

my application is MVC3 ASPX C#; I am trying to enable/disable  Html.EditorFor using the following:
In the Model:

```
 public bool IsReadOnly { get; private set; }
```

In the controller:

```
   if (MySession.Current._progress == 100)
       ViewData["ReadOnly"] = true;
```

In the view:

```
... Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Models.CTAHFormEdit>" %>
 <script runat="server" type="text/C#">
        bool isReadOnly = false;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if ((bool?)this.ViewData["ReadOnly"] == true)this.isReadOnly = true;
        }
    </script>
    <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.Vessel_calcification, Model.IsReadOnly)%>
```

This did not work.  I also tried:

```
  <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.Subject_motion, new { @disable = true })%>
```

did not work also!

The best solution, becasue I also have dropdownlist and checkbox in the same view is to use @disable = true and @readonly = true or false and be able to change true of false using a ViewBag.  Any suggestions, thanks in adavance.

Comment: Have you attempted to create a custom EditorFor? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497183/how-to-create-custom-editor-display-templates-in-asp-net-mvc-3  I generally just build my view statically instead of building the custom EditorFor, but that's probably not good OO advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Subject_motion, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
```

Here's an explanation of the difference between EditorFor and TextBoxFor:

[Differences between Html.TextboxFor and Html.EditorFor in MVC and Razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826173/mvc3-html-textboxfor-vs-html-editorfor)

Comment: TextBoxFor did not work for my application becasue I am using bit fields that shows as a check box; rather than changing all fields; I made a new view and replaced EditorFor to Html.DisplayFor, and just redirected to that veiew from the controller.  Thanks