# MVC5 and Bootstrap3: Html.EditorFor wrong class? How to change?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I just noticed that MVC 5 is using a different class for input fields when using EditorFor. I think its from a lower version of bootstrap, so the current class doesn't really add up.

I'm talking about this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Contact.CellphoneNo, new { @class = "control-label col-md-4"})
       <div class="col-md-8">
           @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Contact.CellphoneNo)
           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Contact.CellphoneNo)
       </div>
</div>
```

Which results to this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-4" for="Contact_CellphoneNo">CellphoneNo</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <input class="text-box single-line" id="Contact_CellphoneNo" name="Contact.CellphoneNo" type="text" value="">
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Contact.CellphoneNo" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

When you look at the  tag, it has a **"text-box"** class instead of Bootstrap3's **"form-control"**

I think I read around somewhere that this was due to the fact of MVC5 switching to Bootstrap 3 at the last minute or something.

---

Question is: How do I change that class manually? I want to be able to change text-box to form-control. I can't really find the code though.

I've also tried this already

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.CivilStatus, new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CivilStatus)
```

Which doesn't seem to work. I'm stumped. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 57, accepted):

EditorFor doesn't accept HTML attributes as a parameter. The parameter you are using is actually `additionalViewData`

Use TextBoxFor instead

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

**Edit**

As of MVC 5.1, HTML attributes can be passed to the EditorTemplate using this syntax

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.UserName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

Comment: Hi @LostInComputer! Thank you for your input. Would TextBoxFor have the same functionality as EditFor?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826173/differences-between-html-textboxfor-and-html-editorfor-in-mvc-and-razor. Everyone's answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the MVC 5 or prior version use `@Html.TextBoxFor` instead of `@Html.EditorFor` as given in the following code:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CivilStatus,new { @class = "form-control" }
```

and if you also have to bind it knockout.js modelview attribute then:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CivilStatus, new { data_bind="value: author.civilStatus", @class = "form-control" })
```

I have used this with MVC4, it's working for me:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName, new { data_bind="value: author.firstName", @class = "form-control" })
```