# How to insert my model properties into this login bootstrap form?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to put the model properties in this styled login form? I don't know where to put the lambda helpers (x=>x.email, x=>x.password etc). Any help is appreciated.

```
@model User

@using (Html.BeginForm("LogIn", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <p><br></p>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="page-header">
                        <h3>Welcome Back! Please Sign In</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Username)
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></span>
                            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Username, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } }) 
                        </div>
                    </div>                       
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Password)
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span></span>
                            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } }) 
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <hr />
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></span> Back</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</button>
                    <div>
                        <h3 class="page-header">No Account? Sign Up, Its Free</h3>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" />
                    Sign Up
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Edit:

the problem is now that i can't apply the wanted style on the input
i tried adding
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Username, new { htmlAttributes = new{@class = "form-control"}}) and this also  @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Username, new { @class = "form-control"}) and both doesnt work.

with adding above i`m trying to get this style:
[image]

but instead i'm getting these unstyled input boxes

[image]

2nd EDIT:

Instead of using :

@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Username, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })

I tried :

@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Username, new { @class = "form-control" })

and with this i'm getting the desired style, so i don`t exactly know the difference between Html.EditorFor and Html.TextBoxFor and if using Html.TextBoxFor is a good solution, maybe someone can clarify this.

Comment: Replace `<input type="email"..` with `@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Email)`, same goes for password.

Comment: Can you post your 'new' View code please.

Comment: That is the new view code... or am i missing something?

Comment: You need to add the `form-control` class to your input fields: `@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Username, new { class="form-control" })`

Comment: @markpsmith You can see in my "Edit" part of the post that i have already tried that too, and it`s not working...

Comment: ah yes, apologies I didn't see the edit.  Can you confirm that your inputs have the `form-control` class using Firebug or similar?

Comment: markpsmith, im using google chrome, and when i inspect the input field has a class="text-box single-line", but now i tried this @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Username, new { @class = "form-control" })
and im getting what i wanted at least visually, so i changed the EditorFor, so is this a good solution or bad?

Comment: No that's fine, I assumed editorfor would render a textbox anyway, but obviously it added extra classes which prevented it from looking right.

Comment: I updated my answer with a link to show the differences between `EditorFor` and `TextboxFor`

Answer (score 1):

As long as your Model is declared you can just change it to this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <p><br></p>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="page-header">
                        <h3>Welcome Back! Please Sign In</h3>
                    </div>
                    <form role="form" method="post" action="/Users/LogIn">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Username)
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></span>
                                @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Username)
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Password)
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span></span>
                                @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Password)
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr />
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></span> Back</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</button>                        
                        <div>
                            <h3 class="page-header">No Account? Sign Up, Its Free</h3>
                        </div>                        
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                            Sign Up
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span>
                        </button>                        
                    </form>                   
                </div>                
            </div>            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also instead of using `<form role="form" method="post" action="/Users/LogIn">` you can do the following:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("LogIn", "Users", FormMethod.Post))
{
// DisplayFor and EditorFor code
}
```

You can read about the differences between and `EditorFor` and a `TextBoxFor` [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826173/differences-between-html-textboxfor-and-html-editorfor-in-mvc-and-razor)

Comment: Thanks that seems to work, but i'm getting weird style on the input boxes so i tried to add htmlAttributes 
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Username, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class="form-control", placeholder="enter username" } })
but it doesn't show, any workaround for this to get the desired style?

Comment: What doesn't show? I'm not sure about the styling but remove all of the classes in the example and add the htmlAttributes like you are doing. It should work fine.

Comment: im getting this http://i.imgur.com/du7UfCp.png,  but instead i want to get this http://i.imgur.com/0FmaItW.png,
so when i add this line 
new { htmlAttributes = new { @class="form-control" } })
the style doesn`t want to apply.

Comment: The form is not applying the style, can you edit your original question and add in the problem to the bottom with the View code please so I can update the answer